# How to apply tags for spot requests made by aws_autoscaling_group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I use terraform for create asg with launch configuration market_type=spot. 
Asg makes spot request, but it has no tags.
Instances have tags from asg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a limitation from AWS. The tags are not applied on Spot instances automatically. You need to put in a mechanism to trap the new instance id and apply the tags. Here is the offical documentation

> You can assign a tag to a Spot Instance request after you create it.
>   The tags that you create for your Spot Instance requests only apply to
>   the requests. These tags are not added automatically to the Spot
>   Instance that the Spot service launches to fulfill the request. You
>   must add tags to a Spot Instance yourself after the Spot Instance is
>   launched.

[Tagging Spot Instance Requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-requests.html#concepts-spot-instances-request-tags)